# Is it better to have AWS EC2 and RDS is the same Availability Zone?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, amazon-aws

I run a web app in an AWS EC2 instance and the database for the app in an RDS instance both in Amazon Web Services Region East-1. However, one of them is in Availability Zone 1a and the other is in 1d. Am I getting all the speed benefits of having both instances in the same "data center" (East-1) even if they are in different Availability Zones, or can I optimize by moving them to the same Availability Zone?

Answer (score 4):

You should have your website and your database in the same availability zone.

- It should be faster
- You are less exposed to the risk of an availability zone going down.   When you spread your web server and database between two, your website goes down if *either* of them goes down.

RDS has an option to have a hot spare of the database running in another availability zone.  This is called a "Multi-AZ deployment".  Similarly you can run a second webserver in another availablility zone and set a load balancer to fail over to it automatically.  That would be the correct way to use multiple availability zones and keep your website running even when one goes down.